# How to write a custom Button component?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, custom-component

I have been making components for Delphi for a couple months now. Currently I am extending the TButton to create another form that has 20 or so components on it. I have done this recently and just created everything dynamically in click event. Is there a way to create to form and have it compiled into the component so I can use the IDE to design the form?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Simply add your TForm unit to your button's Package, and then you can design it like any other project.